# auto click in C# in difrent position of screen

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i need to ceate a program that click in 3 Position in screen . but i have problem .

1 - how move mouse in screen ?

2 - how click in position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in WPF you can use this line of code to set mouse position

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

this line to firing the event

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
```

and this for simulate the click mouse

```
private static void LeftMouseClick(int Xposition, int Yposition)
{
    SetCursorPos(Xposition, Yposition)
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, Xposition, Yposition, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, Xposition, Yposition, 0, 0);
}
```

and trigger the click you should call the LeftMouseClick;

for example:

```
LeftMouseClick(11, 15);
```

You can see this links about thoes functions

[SetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx)

[mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx)